# How to convert json string to varbinary in SQL Server / Oracle / Postgres?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How do I convert a json string to `varbinary` in SQL?

I tried the below query in SQL Server:

```
  SELECT CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), '[{"name": "John","skills": ["SQL", "C#", "Azure"]}, {"name": "Jane","surname": "Doe"}]', 1);
```

but it throws this error:

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 7
>   Error converting data type varchar to varbinary.

How do I solve this?

Comment: Not sure what `varbinary` is supposed to be in the context of Postgres or Oracle. `bytea` and `blob`?

Comment: yes varbainary is for sqlserver. But i want to achieve similar functionality using appropriate functions and datatypes in all the dbs(postgres/oracle). The sample query is fr sql server

Comment: Thanks but i couldn't find any help there :(

Comment: For some reason COMPRESS and DECOMPRESS pops to mind, but JSON should really be stored into a NVARCHAR datatypes as the native JSON function only work on that datatype talking about SQL Server (MSSQL) here..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are specifying a Style value of 1 when making the conversion, which only works if the expression being converted is a character expression with an even number of hexadecimal digits. Since the JSON is a noncharacter expression, you should be using a Style value of 0.

This should work just fine:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARBINARY(max), '[{"name": "John","skills": ["SQL", "C#", "Azure"]}, {"name": "Jane","surname": "Doe"}]', 0);
```

More information can be found [in documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#binary-styles).

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is

```
select  convert(varbinary(100), 'sql server version')
```

[sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/51118/0)